# how to create autocomplete from google.maps.places.autocomplete in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

Please correct me if I'm wrong...
I write a code with no errors, in before edit this post.
but after i read a comment about how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. I'm very confuse, because my minimal script before didn't work, i cann't include complete code, because my complex code, and I don't have verifiable example.

I just need to know how to create autocomplete from google.maps.places to autocomplete my textfield in EXTJS.

Thanks before..

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry, i put it wrong place. Please don't vote me down, I've edited the code...

Comment: MCVE! Read the above comment!

Comment: MCVE means that you should provide code, stripped down to the minimum required that allows to reproduce the issue, but complete in a way that we can basically just copy/paste it to verify what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this question from [@Rob Schmuecker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1672632/rob-schmuecker) answers.
So, the focus of this question about using an appropriate proxy to call the json from google like using :

```
addressModel.getProxy().setExtraParam('url', 'http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + queryString + '&sensor=false');
```

to set the params dynamically, from this data model :

```
addressModel = Ext.define("Addresses", {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'https://jsonp.nodejitsu.com',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'results',
            totalProperty: 'totalCount'
        }
    },

    fields: ['formatted_address']
});
```

after that you can create a combobox and add listener to the combobox each keyup to call the extraparam in your proxy.

this is the demo from @Rob Schmuecker :
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/g70

and this is for the complete answer from Rob, who solved my problem :
[Check This...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27888617/google-maps-api-v3-can-i-create-place-autocomplete-in-combobox-using-extjs-4-2)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to solve this using the Google Places-Library.

**My Solution using Ext JS 3.4**

1) Integrate the Google Places API
2) Create a custom Proxy (I've had extended the Ext.data.DataProxy)
2a) Set the proxy api (read: true)
2b) override the doRequest method. there you can make the calls to i.e. google.maps.PlacesService.textSearch
2c) Handle the Places Request using a Reader (I've created my custom reader)
3) store your data in a store (I've created my custom store)
4) create component that consumes data from the store

Be aware that your application has to comply to the Google Maps/Google Earth APIs Terms of Service! (You Have to show the logos, third party right holders, ect.)

There you have it!

Comment: you use google.maps.PlacesService to retrieve places ?
I'm a little bit confuse about using PlacesService or i use google.maps.places.AutocompleteService class to retrieve place prediction.
can you give me a little code snippet if you've figured it out.
just to know how you put that in your textfield to show the autocomplete.
Thanks before...

Comment: Basically it's all about the custom store, proxy and reader because that's how components consume data in Ext JS. Be sure that you are aware of these concepts. Ext.form.TextField won't work on the fly because this component does not contain an option to store information. I had gone for a solution using Ext.form.ComboBox my self.

Posting the my whole code would be to complex because I've created an small library for exactly this problem.

Comment: yes, you're right about autocomplete won't work in textfield because i've try it many time, I get the data prediction when i inspect the element, but the predictions didn't show up. so using xtype:textfield didn't work, but as you mention about using combo box, maybe you can give me a little code snippet not a whole code, just code snippet for your data proxy to retrieve autocomplete predictions. thanks.

Comment: This post should clarify it:

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?250498-SOLVED-Google-geocode-and-doRequest-with-Ext.data.proxy.Ajaxthis

Comment: your link : http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?250498-SOLVED-Google-geocode-and-doRequest-with-Ext.data.proxy.Ajaxthis

didn't show anything.